# How to print the margin ratio being used by geometry?

Tags: margins, geometry

I am trying to access a parameter used by package `geometry`, shown below

[image: layout]

it is one inch for `a4paper`, but it could be different for example, in `c4paper`. I could not find a native command that holds this value, could you please help me with this?

Or equivalently, if we can access the ratio of top margin and bottom margin, we can compute for that value, but it is also hard to access. The ratio is 2 to 3 by default, but it can be set differently, how could I access it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The parameter two is simply 1in + `\voffset`. You can get it as `\dimexpr 1in+\voffset` and you can print it as `\the\dimexpr 1in+\voffset`. This complication implies from old and not so good decision that the page origin in TeX is at the 1in 1in coordinate.

Comment: @wipet You are right, thanks!